# How to get the tag.contents

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, libxml2

I have this XML:

```
<record>
    <f id="27">John Smith</f>
    <f id="28"/>
</record>
```

and parse it with Nokogiri this way:

```
# I get the record from the whole document
... 
fields = record.xpath("f")
for field in fields
    puts field.content
end
```

which returns this:

```
John Smith
\n 28 \n
```

This is incorrect. The second `field` tag does not have anything inside the tag, it should return an empty value. Right?

By the way, the same thing happens with LibXML.

This is the Actual code:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML("<?xml version="1.0" ?><records><record><f id="27">John Smith</f><f id="38"/></record></records>")

records = xml.xpath("//record")
records.map{|record|
    fields = record.xpath("f")
    fields.to_enum(:each_with_index).collect{|field,index|
        [field.content, index]
    }
}
```

Comment: weird, works for me (changing xpath to '//f'). Show us how you create "record". Note also that in Ruby for-loops are extremely non-idiomatic (use Enumerable#each instead)

Comment: There is a `records` variable also and I get the `record` from `records.each{|record| ... }` and `records` comes from `SOMEXML.xpath("//record")`. I actually use .each, not the for-loop.

Comment: it's easier if you paste the exact (but shortest) XML and code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: works for me: [[["John Smith", 0], ["", 1]]]. Nokogiri 1.5.0

Comment: Wow, sorry, my mistake. I didn't check all of the actual XML. The actual XML had this in it: `<f>John Smith</f><f><id>28</id></f>`. I think it added `<id>28</id>` when the actual field was empty. I guess the actual code is correct, it was just my mistake.

Comment: In general, I recommend not using the `xpath()` method unless you are specifically searching for an XPath. Instead, use Nokogiri's `search` and `at` methods to search using CSS-style accessors. They're easier on the eyes. Note that `xpath('f')` is not the same as `search('f')` because of syntactic differences in XPath and CSS. Also, in your actual code, I'd write: `record.xpath('//f').each_with_index { ... }` or `record.search('f').each_with_index { ... }` or use the `each.with_index` variant.

Comment: In this code, I need to use the specific `xpath`. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer the question. The tag probably contains other tags in it that you might've missed.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath accessor is wrong:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<record>
    <f id="27">John Smith</f>
    <f id="28"/>
</record>
EOT

puts doc.xpath('f').size # => 0
puts doc.xpath('//f').size # => 2

puts doc.xpath('//f[@id="27"]').size # => 1
puts doc.xpath('//f[@id="27"]').first.text # => "John Smith"
puts doc.at('//f').text # => "John Smith"
```

Nokogiri always returns a NodeSet with the `xpath`, `css` and `search` methods, and a Node for `at` and its aliases. Treat the NodeSet as an array.

```
doc.xpath('//f[@id="27"]').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet < Object
doc.at('//f[@id="27"]').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element < Nokogiri::XML::Node
```